# How to save my $date from the last time the user uploaded php via .txt

Tags: php, text

I want it so that when my users upload a document I can present on the page the time the document was uploaded and therefore if they were to refresh the page the time the document was uploaded would still be there. I have a document to store the time with which is updateLog.txt and is empty at the moment. This is what I've currently got:

```
date_default_timezone_set('United Kingdome/Londone');
$date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', time());

$myFile=fopen("uploadLog.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
fwrite($myFile, $_POST[$date]."\r\n");
fclose($myFile);
```

But nothing is saving to the document?

Comment: shouldn't $_POST[$date] be just $date .?

Comment: ha ha ha... That is the magic of fault!

Comment: @DemoUser what do you suggest I change here then?

Comment: you have to open this file as `append` mode, so that your date append to the file. if you want to retrieve the data then just read the file. and go for the last data which is your last access.

Comment: for more details, [see this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp)

Comment: Also just use a database man! Whatcu doin storing userdata in .txt files! This is 2016!

Comment: @FrayneKonok I don't want to open the file I just want to be able to pull data from it in a php document

Comment: [see this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp), and without opening the file you can't pull data from it.

Comment: @Glubus is totally right, storing data in .txt is in most cases nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used $_POST[$date] instead of $date and a wrong time zone name.
The corresponding time zone would be `Europe/London`.
You can find a full list of time zones here:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Your code should look like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', time());

$myFile = fopen("uploadLog.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
fwrite($myFile, $date."\r\n");
fclose($myFile);
```

If you want to append to the file, use `a` as mode insted of `w` for `fopen`:

```
$myFile = fopen("uploadLog.txt","a") or exit("Can’t open file!");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you

Comment: After `$myFile = fopen("uploadLog.txt","a") or exit("Can’t open file!");` how would I get it to echo the information in the document?

Comment: `Worked perfectly` what?

Answer (score 0):

File opening mode `a+`, Open a file for `read/write`.

The existing data in file is preserved. File pointer starts at the end of the file. Creates a new file if the file doesn't exist.

`a` is use to write something to the file, `w` also do the same thing, but the difference is if we open a file as `a` mode then the data are stores like stack, if we open a file as `w` mode then it will Erases the contents of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist. File pointer starts at the beginning of the file.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', time());

$myFile=fopen("uploadLog.txt","a+") or exit("Can’t open file!");
fwrite($myFile, $date."\r\n");


//If you want to read the file, then Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($myFile)) {
  echo fgets($myFile) . "<br>"; //data pull to the php
}
fclose($myFile);
```